# link_url substitution tokens

Tags: facebook, ads, substitution, facebook-ads-api

Some search engines support a set of substitution tokens that get replaced at run-time ( ie when a creative is served ). Does Facebook support any substitution tokens? Where can I find this documented? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay in responding. Here is an example that demonstrates what we're trying to do. Take the link_url:

http://www.some-domain.com/page/{TOKEN}

At the time of serving, Facebook would replace {TOKEN} with the creative id. This actually used to work with the {FACEBOOK} token, eg:

http://www.some-domain.com/page/{FACEBOOK}

This is important because it allows us to extract the creative id from the final destination url ( where it hits our server ), and link it to the creative id in Facebook reports.

I'm not sure what happened to the {FACEBOOK} token, but it no longer works.